# ButterWorth low pass filter (BLPF) don't filter the image properly (c++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, image-processing

This is my code for low pass filter implementation but it can't filter the image properly.

What am I missing to make it a butterworth filter of order 2?

Input:  F - 2D coefficients of the FFT image
Output: LF - ButterWorth filtered coefficients

```
void BLPF(Complex<double> *F, Complex<double> *LF, int width, int height) 
{
    int i, j ;
    int Df ;
    int centerX, centerY ;

    centerX = width / 2 ;
    centerY = height / 2 ;
    Df = 32 ;

    for(j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for(i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            if((i - centerX) * (i - centerX) + (j - centerY) * (j - centerY) > Df * Df) {
                LF[i + j * width] = 0.0 ;
            } else {
                LF[i + j * width] = F[i + j * width] ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using two fixed values for the frequency response, 1.0 and 0.0 depending on ω<sub>x</sub> and ω<sub>y</sub>. A proper filter uses values in between.